# "yo" (Node/Javascript module) installation failed

Tags: nodejs, npm

i have been trying to install yo, but keep getting this errors, anyone please help.

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/hubot# npm install -g yo
\
> spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall 


fs.js:439
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync/package.json'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:978:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync/postinstall.js:20:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:935:3
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-16-generic 
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall script 'node postinstall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the spawn-sync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node postinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls spawn-sync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/hubot/npm-debug.log
```

current versions of nodejs
v0.10.25
and npm
1.4.21

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem, maybe this will help you:

```
sudo npm install -g yo --unsafe-perm
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570698/permission-denied-while-installing-yo